# How to apply CSS on an element in innerHTML with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, innerhtml

I am using CKEditor. I have the html in a textarea. I want to get that HTML. And want to apply a class on the body tag in that markup.

`jQuery('#htmlData').val()` gives me the HTML.

How can I apply a class in the body tag present in this `val()`? Do I need to use `html()`?

I need the selector for this.

Comment: are you appending that html to some DOM element afterwards ?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery(jQuery('#htmlData').val()).css('color','red');

Do you have a live example/demo?

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
jQuery("body", jQuery('#htmlData').val()).addClass("something");
```